# sliding window calculation with panel data in influxDB

Tags: time-series, influxdb, panel-data, dolphindb

I am given the not-so-enviable job of comparing time-series databases for a project. One thing we need to do pretty often is to sliding window calculations with panel data. For example, to calculate a one year sliding window volatility for each stock, in DolphinDB we can write just one line of code which is pretty neat：
`select symbol, mvol(ret, 252) from t context by symbol`
Does anyone know how to do the same in InfluxDB?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all available supporting algorithmic functions for influxDB [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/). I am not hundred percentage sure, but I doubt you are looking for something similar to [moving_average](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#moving-average) or [derivative](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#derivative)

Comment: I was looking for moving average for multiple stocks. For example, if you have 8000 stocks and each stocks have 1000 days of data, and you need to do a moving average for each of them. How do you do it in InfluxDB?